# Expanding ADF table row programatically on clicking commandLink

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a column displaying author name and a command link "Show Documents". I want to expand the row on click of Show Documents command Link as happens on clicking detailStamp facet icon.

Here comes the JSFF code:

```
<af:table var="row" rowBandingInterval="0" id="rohitT"
        value="#{pageFlowScope.parseData.AList}" rowSelection="multiple" 
        binding="#{pageFlowScope.parseData.dataTable}"
        disclosedRowKeys="#{pageFlowScope.parseData.disclosedKeys}">
        <af:column sortable="false" headerText="Author" id="c3">
  <af:outputText value="#{row.author}" id="ot5"/>
  <af:commandLink text="Show Documents" id="sd"
                  actionListener="#{pageFlowScope.parseData.prepareLOV}" partialSubmit="true" >

  </af:commandLink>
  <af:outputText value="Disclosed Key::#{pageFlowScope.parseData.disclosedKeys}"
                id="ot6"/>
  </af:column>
<af:column sortable="false" headerText="Subject area" id="c2">
  <af:outputText value="#{row.subjectArea}" id="ot4"/>
</af:column>
<af:column sortable="false" headerText="Select" id="c1">
             <af:selectBooleanCheckbox id="sbc1" selected="false" autoSubmit="true" 
              disabled="#{pageFlowScope.optionSelected ne 'Default' and pageFlowScope.optionSelected ne 'One'}"   valueChangeListener="#{pageFlowScope.parseData.onChange}"/>
             <af:outputText value="PageFlow::#{pageFlowScope.optionSelected}"
                            id="ot3"/></af:column>
  <f:facet name="detailStamp" >
   <af:group id="g1">


    <af:selectOneListbox label="Label 1" id="sol1"
                           value="#{pageFlowScope.parseData.selectedValues}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{pageFlowScope.parseData.allValuesList}"
                       id="si2"/>
      </af:selectOneListbox>
    </af:group>
  </f:facet>
</af:table>
```

Here comes the managed bean code:

```
    List selectedValues;
    private RowKeySetImpl disclosedKeys=null;
    List<SelectItem> allValuesList;
    public void setDisclosedKeys(RowKeySetImpl disclosedKeys) {
        this.disclosedKeys = disclosedKeys;
    }


    public void setAllValuesList(List<SelectItem> allValuesList) {
        this.allValuesList = allValuesList;
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getAllValuesList() {
        if (allValuesList == null) {
                   allValuesList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
                   allValuesList.add(new SelectItem(1, "India"));
                   allValuesList.add(new SelectItem(2, "Australia"));
                   allValuesList.add(new SelectItem(3, "America"));
                   allValuesList.add(new SelectItem(4, "United Kingdom"));
               }
               return allValuesList;
    }
    public void setSelectedValues(List selectedValues) {
        this.selectedValues = selectedValues;
    }

    public List getSelectedValues() {
        if (selectedValues == null) {
            selectedValues = new ArrayList();
            selectedValues.add(1);
            selectedValues.add(3);
            System.out.println("List is-" + selectedValues);
        }
        return selectedValues;
    }

    public void setDisclosedKeys(RowKeySetImpl disclosedKeys) {
        this.disclosedKeys = disclosedKeys;
    }

    public RowKeySetImpl getDisclosedKeys() {
        return disclosedKeys;
    }
    public void prepareLOV(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
       disclosedKeys =null; 
           callDetailStamp();
       RowKeySetImpl testDisclosedKey=getDisclosedKeys();
        System.out.println("testDisclosedKey before refresh::"+testDisclosedKey);
       AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(getDataTable());
       }

           private void callDetailStamp() {
        RowKeySet rks = getDataTable().getSelectedRowKeys();
        Key currentKey = null;
        Object objKey=null;
        Iterator rksIter = rks.iterator();
        while (rksIter.hasNext()) 
                {
        System.out.println("Entered Loop");

        objKey=(Object)rksIter.next();
        System.out.println("Obj Key::"+objKey);
    }
    if (rks.size()>0) { 
               System.out.println("Setting disclosed keys");
            disclosedKeys = new RowKeySetImpl(); 

           if (getDataTable() != null) { 

                 ArrayList newKeys = new ArrayList(); 
                 ArrayList temp = new ArrayList();             
                 temp.add(0,objKey);
                 newKeys.add(temp); 
                 disclosedKeys.addAll(newKeys); 
             } 
           } 


    else
    {
        disclosedKeys = new RowKeySetImpl(); 
    }
    System.out.println("Disclosed Key::"+disclosedKeys.toString());
    setDisclosedKeys(disclosedKeys);

}
```

I think I am able to set disclosedRowKeys property as I am able to print its value in output text. Whatever row I select, I get the disclosedKeyValue as an Array of index of the particular selected row. Clicking on link sets disclosedKeys value and refreshes the table but not expanding the row. Am I missing out something here ?